# What is life according to Hinduism?

Tags: life

Well I have read that life is a suffering according to Buddhism but I am a Hindu , what is life according to Hinduism?Should you be happy or not ? I am really confused.

Comment: Also there is similar question present- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3020/what-is-death-and-life.

Comment: There are no good answers present of your query in  both the above. Unfortunately the question is duplicate and so probably will be closed. But it will be better if you slightly change your question and add something specific , I will be happy to retract close vote.

Comment: Well, the Buddhist sentiment isn't aspirational.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between Hinduism and Buddhism on this issue.

**Ocean of Life – Need for Moksha**

> "That Ocean, so terrible has sorrow for its waters. Anxiety and grief
> constitute its deep lakes. Disease and Death are its gigantic
> alligators. The great fears that strike the heart at every step are
> its huge snakes. The deeds inspired by Tamas are its tortoises. Those
> inspired by Rajas are its fishes. Wisdom constitutes the raft for
> crossing it. The affections entertained for objects of the senses are
> its mire. Decrepitude constitutes its region of grief and trouble.
> Knowledge..is its island. Acts constitute its great depth. Truth is
> its shores. Pious observances constitute the verdant weeds floating on
> its bosom. Envy constitutes its rapid and mighty current. The diverse
> sentiments of the heart constitute its mines. The diverse kinds of
> gratification are its valuable gems. Grief and fever are its winds.
> Misery and thirst are its mighty eddies. Painful and fatal diseases
> are its huge elephants. The assemblages of bones are its flight of
> steps and phlegm is its froth. Gifts are its pearl-banks. The lakes of
> blood are its corals. Loud laughter constitutes its roars. Diverse
> sciences are its impassibility. Tears are its brine. Renunciation of
> company constitutes the high refuge (of those that seek to cross it).
> Children and spouses are its unnumbered leeches. Friends and kinsmen
> are the cities and towns on its shores. Abstention from injury and
> Truth are its boundary line. Death is its storm-wave. The knowledge of
> Vedanta is its island (capable of affording refuge to those that are
> tossed upon its waters). Acts of compassion towards all creatures
> constitute its life-buoys, and Emancipation is the priceless commodity
> offered to those voyaging on the waters in search of merchandise. "

**Mahabharata Santi Parva Section CCCIII**

**Should you be happy or not?**

Yes, happiness is always the objective. However, eternal happiness is impossible in the relative world. Death will snatch away all happiness. Hence attaining moksha is the prescription for eternal happiness.

> That which is infinite, is alone happiness. There is no happiness in
> anything finite. The infinite alone is happiness. But one must desire
> to understand the infinite. 'Reverend Si, I desire to understand the
> infinite'

**Chandogya Upanishad 7.23.1**

> Bhuman [infinite] is a profound term supplied by this Upanishad to Vedanta. Sri
> Sankaracharya renders the meaning of it by the words Mahat and
> Niratisayam. Mahat and Brhat are synonymous. The word Brahman is
> derived from the root 'Brh', meaning to grow. Hence, therefore, the
> terms Bhuman, Mahat, and Brahman denote the same reality which
> includes all finite existences and outside which one cannot conceive
> anything greater in magnitude or value. Anything short of this
> infinite, all-inclusive reality, is only limited, petty and finite. It
> is common experience that the human mind cannot choose anything small
> when something greater than that is within its knowledge. Man is not
> happy with the small, he wants something more than what he already
> possesses and until the very limit of expansion is reached he cannot
> find complete contentment. Limitedness and un-limitedness are
> relative. The former implies the later. The latter is not obtained by
> the common man and hence we find that his restlessness and craving are
> expressed through his activities. The infinite alone transcends all
> relations and includes within its range all the desires, hopes, and
> aspirations of man. Hence this Bhuman alone is declared to be
> unequalled, unlimited and unsurpassed bliss. This is the summit of
> Vedanta and the goal of all religious and philosophical search. This
> Upanishad refers to this very principle by other terms also, such as
> Om, Sat, Atman and Brahman with different connotations to explain
> various doctrines connected with contemplation and creation of the
> universe.

**Commentary on Chandogya Upanishad 7.23.1 by Swami Swahananda**

Answer (score 1):

Iam not a scholar on vedas or hinduism but as far as i know Hinduism is a multitude of differing views.

Darshan means to see, it is said that beauty lies in the eyes of the beholder.

It means how you see .....it is shown like that.

The philosophy of Hinduism accommodates differing views ie both astika and nastika and if you ask me to give a single view, then iam not sure.

My recommendation is please dont mortgage your life to "isms". It a precious opportunity given to you

So ask yourself what my view of life

Going inward is the way forward sir.

You hold the key to unlock your life sir...once you unlock...do that please

After doing that come back and ask me sir , i will quote some literature from hinduism that suits your view

सर्वं खल्विदं ब्रह्म तज्जलानिति शान्त उपासीत । अथ खलु क्रतुमयः पुरुषो यथाक्रतुरस्मिँल्लोके पुरुषो भवति तथेतः प्रेत्य भवति स क्रतुं कुर्वीत ॥ ३.१४.१ ॥

sarvaṃ khalvidaṃ brahma tajjalāniti śānta upāsīta | atha khalu kratumayaḥ puruṣo yathākraturasmim̐lloke puruṣo bhavati tathetaḥ pretya bhavati sa kratuṃ kurvīta || 3.14.1 ||

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.